# No-Flash multiple images uploader script with options for every upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I need a no-flash images uploader script that supports:

- Multiple Uploads
- Drag & Drop
- Progress bar for every upload
- Small preview for every upload
- Resumable downloads
- Selectable preferences for every upload

So something like this script: [jQuery-File-Upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/)

A screenshot:

[image]

But I need to add some options for every upload, for example: "Title" and "Category", than I need to run a function for every upload that takes the submitted datas e puts them into my database, is there any way I can do it?

Comment: Have you even tried anything? If so, describe what you've tried so far

Comment: No, I have not found a script that lets me add preferences for every upload

Answer (score 0):

If you use the templates that come with jQuery-File-Upload, you can add in your own fields that appear when each item is added to the queue. The plugin will need to know about these fields, so you can use the callback to add more data:

```
$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
    // get content from the new input fields
    var inputs = data.context.find('select'); // or whatever inputs you added

    // assign values to data.formData
    // you can simply $.extend() the new inputs with $(this), and $.serializeArray() both
    data.formData = $.extend(inputs.serializeArray(), $(this).serializeArray());
});
```

See [this](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-submit-additional-Form-Data) for more information.